# JMSSerializerBundle Yaml config for custom entity class

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I've got in my symfony2 project, a custom entity outside Bundles and framework.

I need set json data into this entity, but i can't apply right configuration to user yaml file.

app/config/config.yml

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            CORE:
                namespace_prefix: "Core\Domain\Model"
                path: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/serializer/CORE"
```

app/Resources/serializer/CORE/Model.Product.yml

```
Core\Domain\Model\Product\Product:
    properties:
        id:
            type: integer
        objectId:
            type: string
        name:
            type: string ...
```

It's possible that this bundle dont works fine with entities outside bundles?.

Always I see error message: You must define a type for Core\Domain\Model\Product\Product::$id.

I think that JMSSerializerBundle don't read yaml file, because with annotations works fine.

Any idea?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In your `app/config/config.yml` be sure to use `\\` as namespace separator instead of `\`:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            CORE:
                namespace_prefix: "Core\\Domain\\Model"
                path: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/serializer/CORE"
```

Otherwise the backslashes are treated as escape characters for the following letters.

**Edit:**
Also make sure to name the JMS serializer config properly. For the class `Core\Domain\Model\Product\Product` you need a `Product.Product.yml` file inside the specified `path` of the config. In your example, your file is named `Model.Product.yml`.

So to get the serializer config file name for an entitiy in general:

1. Strip the `namespace` defined in the config from the class name
2. replace the namespace separators `\` with `.`
3. append `.yml` and put the file in the `path` folder defined in the config

Comment: I've just updated the answer as I've noticed an additional mistake in the file naming.

Comment: I'm not sure that understand you.

I changed Product.yml by Product.Product.yml, and result is the same.

I changed too Product.yml by Core.Domain.Model.Product.Product.yml, ant result it's the same.

I don't understand what happens.

Comment: [SOLVED]

Works fine with file Products.Products.yml

Needs a cache clear.

Thanks for all.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. I'd appreciate if you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/1262901). Thanks.